# How to set TERM environment variable in ssh configuration?

Tags: ssh

I use this setting in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host server
  Hostname 192.168.x.x
  SetEnv TERM=xterm
```

But when logging in to the server and doing `echo $TERM`, I get `xterm-256color`.

How to set TERM from ssh client config file?

*What is curious: when connecting as `TERM=xterm ssh server`, `echo $TERM` on server gives `xterm`. Although this shows that the setting can be transmitted, it does not solve the problem, because I need to set it in config file. Also, putting `TERM=xterm` in `.ssh/environment` on server sets it, but it does not solve the problem either, because I cannot edit anything on server.*

Comment: I'm wondering this as well, but ended up just creating an alias like so: `alias ssh='env TERM=xterm ssh'` in my .bashrc. I know it's a hack, but it's good enough for my purpose (i.e. st-256color not being recognized by older hosts).

Answer (score 7):

Since OpenSSH 8.7 (2021-08-20), `SetEnv TERM` [is now supported](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7):

> allow ssh_config SetEnv to override $TERM, which is
> otherwise handled specially by the protocol. Useful in ~/.ssh/config
> to set TERM to something generic (e.g. "xterm" instead of
> "xterm-256color") for destinations that lack terminfo entries.

Answer (score 3):

Adjusting the configuration to this can be used as a workaround:

```
Host server
  Hostname 192.168.x.x
  RemoteCommand TERM=xterm $SHELL
  RequestTTY yes
```

Probably worthwhile mentioning it comes with a caveat; the section will no longer work when explicitly giving a command as an argument to ssh, or with sftp, sshfs etc.

Comment: Add `-l` at the end of the remote command to get a login shell like by default.

Answer (score 0):

Only TERM must decide here - one is not supposed to configure that in ssh in any way. One way to deal with this is to use proper terminal (one that uses TERM=xterm). Another way is to create ssh wrapper and check name of desired host in it and in case of match check if TERM is xterm-compatible, and if yes, do `export TERM=xterm` before `exec ssh "$@"`. One may also use the hack to set `TERM=xterm` in `.ssh/environment` on server (assuming that only xterm-compatible terminal will be used to connect to the server).

Use this command:

```
TERM=xterm ssh host
```